# Glassfish loads JavaScript files really slow (> 1 minute)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have a weird problem with my Glassfish-Web application.

Most of the time, my index.jsp site loads really fast. But sometimes (especially after updating a new version of the application), I get a bunch of TimeOutExceptions in Glassfish.

In the Chrome developer console, all JavaScript files are on state 'Pending', the .jsp and .css files however, are loaded very quickly.
After exactly 1 minute (or sometimes 1.5 minutes) most of the JavaScript files are on state '200'. Some of them remain on state 'Failed'.
After reloading the page again, everything works fine.

See screenshots from Chrome.
Pending state:
http://s30.postimg.org/ngr85kuk1/pending.png

Done state:
http://s17.postimg.org/dvdgxmppr/done.png

These errors appear on glassfish:

```
[#|2014-07-25T13:51:12.321+0200|WARNING|glassfish 4.0|javax.enterprise.web._vs.server|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-7;_TimeMillis=1406289072321;_LevelValue=900;|StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copy(DefaultServlet.java:2069)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
    ... 36 more
```

I am using Glasfish 4 Community Edition.

Thanks for your help

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined all JavaScript files to one big file (and minified it) and after that, the problem never occured again.